# Get Facebook Friend List and their Birthdays and Post on their wall i

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api

I want to get Users Friend List and their Birthdays from Facebook.

Can some one help me out as I have read its not possible in recent SDK.
If some one could direct me in right path

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [/me/invitable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2?locale=en_GB)

Comment: invitable_friends is for inviting friends only

Answer (score 1):

You only get the authorized friends. That´s how it works now, you can´t get all friends anymore, at least not for what you want to do.

Btw, what you want to do is not possible anyway, because you can´t get the birthday of friends anymore - friend permissions are deprecated and you can only get the birthday of the authorized user. Also, it´s not possible to post on the wall of a friend - for a very good reason, because it would definitely be spam.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog